# Core-plot configuration error

Tags: iphone, configuration, core-plot

I am trying to use core-plot and I followed the instruction from the following project page to use it.

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications, which is

You can install the SDK with a standard Mac installer package, or by hand. Here is how you install by hand.

1. Copy the CorePlotSDK directory to ~/Library/SDKs/
2. Add to your project's .PCH file:

   #import < CorePlot/CorePlot.h >
3. Open Project -> Edit Project Settings and for All Configurations:

3a. Add to Additional SDKS:
$HOME/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/${PLATFORM_NAME}.sdk

3b. Add to Other Linker Flags:
-ObjC -all_load -lCorePlot

1. Add the QuartzCore framework to the project.
2. Add a CPGraph to your application.

I went with the SDK install options: I installed it with Mac installer Package, it got installed in the following location /Library/SDKs/iphoneos.sdk and /Library/SDKs/iphonesimulator.sdk

Then i did step 2 as mentioned.

**For 3a i added /Library/SDKs/iphonesimulator.sdk**

Then i did 3b and then 4.

After that I tried to do a build and see how does it works and i get the following errors:

:1:0 :1:1: warning: "__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED" redefined

:1:0 :1:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition

/var/folders/+r/+rBG+BziF1OqK12XNyw1ak+++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-cztutytisanvsqaptkdkpoyyctln/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250:0 /var/folders/+r/+rBG+BziF1OqK12XNyw1ak+++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-cztutytisanvsqaptkdkpoyyctln/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250: error: syntax error before '^' token

/var/folders/+r/+rBG+BziF1OqK12XNyw1ak+++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-cztutytisanvsqaptkdkpoyyctln/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250:0 /var/folders/+r/+rBG+BziF1OqK12XNyw1ak+++TM/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.502/CompositeSDKs/iphonesimulator-iPhoneSimulator4.1-cztutytisanvsqaptkdkpoyyctln/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIView.h:250: error: 'type name' declared as function returning a function

This appears 20 times. and it points all to UIView.h

There are same question in the stackoverflow and people suggested to change the compiler to 4.2 and for lot of people it worked, but for me the compiler was always set to 4.2 and still I get the same error.

**On 3a if do /Library/SDKs/iphoneos.sdk**

I get the following error

error: Composite SDK failed: The base SDK uses platform 'iphonesimulator', but an additional SDK uses platform 'iphoneos'. All SDKs must use the same platform (PLATFORM_NAME).

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I have figured out the solution for this error:

Thanks to the developer on core-plot project and sebastien.leduc a google code user for their help.

I am using CorePlotInstaller_0.2.2.zip, and one important steps that is missing on the installation guide is you have to use LLVM GCC 4.2 and not GCC 4.2.

The other important steps which was little confused me was 3a.

Add to Additional SDKS: $HOME/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/${PLATFORM_NAME}.sdk

Here you have to literally add the above line, I was changing the ${PLATFORM_NAME} with iphoneos or iphonesimulator, but **no** we don't have to do that.

One last thing if you don't find the sdk on the following path $HOME/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK

Check out /Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK.

I hope this will help people, it took me about a week to figure out with the help of all the people who came forward to help.

Comment: Thank you!! I had this same problem, so I really appreciate the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a new version of the Core Plot installer that should resolve this issue. You can download it from http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/downloads/list.

You can choose to install Core Plot for all users or just your account. If you install for all users, change the Additional SDKs path from `$HOME/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/${PLATFORM_NAME}.sdk` to `/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/${PLATFORM_NAME}.sdk`.

Comment: Hi Eric, If it helps you I am using 4.1 as base sdk

Answer (score 1):

I integrated core-plot into my application yesterday so it's fresh on my mind. I tried installing the SDK the same way you are and hit the same error. Comments in the google-group recommended NOT going this route, so I went back and installed the source code.

I ended up using the tutorial [HERE](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application) for the basic steps and sample code. The code doesn't work anymore, but all the broken parts are answered in the comments (including a complete reposting of the code which works on the latest version).

Some stumbling points were that the "-ObjC" and "-all_load" flags were both needed, and when I added the header path the "search recursively" option wasn't checked off. Both these questions and many more are answered in the comments.

Comment: Hi Winder, I went over that route too, but that also doesn't work for me. Are you saying it worked for you or are you saying by going over this route also didn't worked for you?

Comment: I built core-plot from source using the tutorial I linked, the SDK did NOT work for me. The tutorial is very outdated, but the project integration part is still good (aside from not mentioning that the "-all_load" flag is needed).

Comment: Thanks Winder, for some reason it didn't work out for me, but yes SDK way of installing is working for me now. You can see from my above answer.